# How to display icon and text below each other with icon in center

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have an `i` tag with background image and then follows `<span>`.
Basically its an icon followed by text. I am trying to align the icon in center and then below the icon the text.
How can I do this?

I tried with vertical align, but it did not work.

```
<li> 
<i class="icons" ></i>
<span>Icon text</span>
<li />
```

CSS :

```
.icons ::before {
content: url(/Style/Image1.svg);
}
```

Comment: FYI you have aquite a few typos. You cannot have a space between the class and `:before` or `::before` (I see you changed it to use `::` as I was typing, but both ways are perfectly fine) Also `<li />` is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this a few ways (once you fix the syntax errors):

**1. Using flexbox**
With flex you only need to style the container element using the right options to make the child elements act as we wish - see the comments:

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;     /* center align the elements in the container */
  flex-direction: column;  /* make the child elements appear one under another */
}

.icons:before {  content: url(https://via.placeholder.com/200x100); }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><i class="icons"></i><span>Icon text 1</span></li>
  <li><i class="icons"></i><span>Icon text 2</span></li>
</ul>
```

**2. Block elements with text-align: center**

```css
/* center-align the container element */
li { text-align: center; list-style: none; }

/* make i and span  block elements so they appear one below the other */
li i, li.span { display: block; }

.icons:before { content: url(https://via.placeholder.com/200x100); }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><i class="icons"></i><span>Icon text 1</span></li>
  <li><i class="icons"></i><span>Icon text 2</span></li>
</ul>
```

**Note - you also have a number of syntax errors:**

- You cannot have a space between the selector and `:before` (or `::before` - both work)
- Also `<li />` is not correct - you close an `li` element using `</li>`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see first error you write `.icon` instead of `.icons` and second just use double `::`

```css
.icons::before {
content: url("https://placeholder.pics/svg/300");
}
```

```html
<i class="icons" ></i>
<span>Icon text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pack them into div styled like this:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <i class="icons" ></i>
    <div>Icon text</div>
</div>
```

Vertical alignment works, when you want to center them putting in one line, but if I understood well you want to put text under the icon, so you should use text-align instead of vertical-align

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler way of doing this

```css
.icons {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.icons::before {
    content: url(https://static2.clutch.co/s3fs-public/logos/r7q9_xgp.png);
}
```

```html
<li>
   <span class="icons">Icon Text here</span>
</li>
```