# icon and test in span elements below each other

Tags: html, css, icons

How can I create icons with text below them in a row, with css?

I currently have this:

```
<div class="icon-stats">
    <div class="video-stats-holder">
        <span class="icon-video-stat"></span><span class="video-stat-descr">12</span>
    </div>  
    <div class="playlist-stats-holder">     
       <span class="icon-playlist-stat"></span><span class="playlist-stat-descr" >5</span> 
    </div>                    
</div>
```

with my css:

```
.icon-stats {
    max-width: 160px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.video-stats-holder, .playlist-stats-holder {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.icon-video-stat, .icon-playlist-stat {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
}

.icon-video-stat {
    background: url('/css/icons/video-stats.png');
}

.icon-playlist-stat {
    background: url('/css/icons/playlist-stats.png');
}
```

The code above is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64097912/how-to-display-icon-and-text-below-each-other-with-icon-in-center) answer, but that doesn't completely work for me, it seems.
The icon and text appear now in one column, all below each other.
I want the icons next to each other, (with the text centered below it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `.icon-stats` class a display property of flex `display:flex`

Just update your CSS with the following code

```
.icon-stats {
    max-width: 160px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
}
```